# Facebook graph api reactions/comments on shares

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am writing a tool to generate reports on my Facebook page performance. I usually do this by copy / pasting numbers from the insights page. But when I'm using the graph api,(I have an access token with all permissions available) I only get numbers for reactions/comments on the publication itself, not on shares. How do I get the total count for reactions/comments on the publication and the shares of the publication ?

Comment: Posts do have their own insights edge, and among the metrics it provides you can see the total reactions and comments made on the post itself plus all the instances in which it has been shared.